# UICollectionView and MVVM

Tags: ios, swift, design-patterns, mvvm

I'm trying to understand how I can use **MVVM** to develop a reusable `UICollectionViewController`.

Suppose you create a view model for each type of `UICollectionViewCell`

```
struct CollectionTestCellViewModel {
    let name: String
    let surname: String

    var identifier: String {
        return CollectionTestCell.identifier
    }

    var size: CGSize?
}
```

And the cell:

```
class CollectionTestCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var surnameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!

    func configure(with viewModel: CollectionTestCellViewModel) {
        surnameLabel.text = viewModel.surname
        nameLabel.text = viewModel.name
    }
}
```

In the view controller I have something like that:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let viewModel = sections[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: viewModel.identifier, for: indexPath)
    configure(view: cell, with: viewModel)
    return cell
}
```

So far no problem.
But consider now this method of `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let viewModel = sections[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    return viewModel.size ?? UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize
}
```

The point is I have layout information (the size of the cell) in the view model. This allows me to put in my view controller the layout delegate methods, but I don't know if this violate the MVVM pattern.

**The final question is:** what should I put inside the view model (of a cell for example)? It is "allowed" to put layout data inside the view model?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In MVVM the View consists of **only visual elements**. We only do things like layout, animation, initializing UI components, etc. There’s a special layer between the View and the Model called the ViewModel.

The ViewModel **provides a set of interfaces**, each of which represents a UI component in the View. We use a technique called “binding” to connection UI components to ViewModel interfaces. So, in MVVM, **we don’t touch the View directly, we deal with business logic in the ViewModel** and thus the View changes itself accordingly.

We write presentational things such as converting `Date` to `String` in the ViewModel instead of the View.

Therefore, **it becomes possible to write a simpler test for the presentational logic without knowing the implementation of the View.**

To learn more about MVVM in iOS [read this article](https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/how-to-use-a-model-view-viewmodel-architecture-for-ios-46963c67be1b).

Comment: I think this sentence is ambiguous:

"The ViewModel provides a set of interfaces, each of which represents a UI component in the View"

This representation can include sizes of UI things, colors, fonts etc.?

Comment: @drakon We create properties with size, color etc. in ViewModel. Then in ViewController (our View in MVVM) create an instance variable of  ViewModel and take values from it.

Comment: @drakon If my answer helped you then don't forget to mark it as the answer)